# R: How to fill up missing year values in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a quite basic R question. I have the following data frame with a year column  that has no 1-year steps.

```
year <- c(1991,1993,1996)
value <-c(3, NA, 4)
```

However, for plotting a line chart, I want to fill the missing years so that I have a series from 1990 to 2000 in 1-year steps. The additional years shall be filled with NA values.

Is there a smart solution to this problem?

Comment: If you're plotting a line chart with `ggplot` then you don't need to fill in the missing data.  You specify what the axes limits and labels should be.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  year = c(1991,1993,1996),
  value = c(3, NA, 4)
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  complete(year = 1990:2000)

print(dat2)
# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#     year value
#    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  1990    NA
#  2  1991     3
#  3  1992    NA
#  4  1993    NA
#  5  1994    NA
#  6  1995    NA
#  7  1996     4
#  8  1997    NA
#  9  1998    NA
# 10  1999    NA
# 11  2000    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R to generate a sequence from 1990 to 2000 and `merge` with original `data.frame`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(1991, 1993, 1996),
                  value = c(3, NA, 4))

merge(df1,
      data.frame(full = seq(1990, 2000))
      by.x = "year",
      by.y = "full",
      all = TRUE)

   year value
1  1990    NA
2  1991     3
3  1992    NA
4  1993    NA
5  1994    NA
6  1995    NA
7  1996     4
8  1997    NA
9  1998    NA
10 1999    NA
11 2000    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We assume that what you have is:

```
dd <- data.frame(year, value)
```

This is a time series so it makes sense to represent it using a time series representation such as ts, zoo or xts.  We convert it to zoo and then to ts.  The latter conversion will fill in the missing years.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dd)
tt <- as.ts(z)
tt
## Time Series:
## Start = 1991 
## End = 1996 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1]  3 NA NA NA NA  4
```

If you really want to convert it to a data frame then use `fortify.zoo(tt)` .

### Plotting

If the only reason to do this is for plotting a line chart then alternately just remove the missing values.   Any of these will work.

```
plot(na.omit(dd), type = "l", xlab = "year", ylab = "value")

plot(na.omit(z), xlab = "year", ylab = "value")

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(na.omit(z)) + xlab("year") + ylab("value")
```

The last plot is shown here:

[image: screnshot]